# IIS and Apache (WAMP) running

Tags: apache, iis, iis-7, iis-6, wamp

How can we run IIS 6 and Apache (wamp) in same machine at same time?

Comment: For 2 or more servers you should give them different ports - 80 for IIS, and 81 for Apache, for example.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

IIS and Apache should have different port.

To change the port of Apache(WAMP)

1. Click on WAMP icon that you can see on your tray or other shortcut icons for wamp.
2. Look for the Apache and open the httpd.conf or if you know where it is stored.
3. Find the "80" then change

   Listen 80 to Listen 8080

   ServerName localhost:80 to ServerName localhost:8080

   Note: You can change the port which you desired as long as it will not conflict with     your other port. It is more safe and common if the port is at this range.
4. Then click on Restart All Services.

See [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5178964_change-number-apache-server-wamp.html) for more info.

If you prefer to change your IIS rather Apache, check on this [IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605)

Comment: I was successful in changing the IIS port to 8080, but Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is still using port 80. Any recommendation on how to kill that service?

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to watch out for is the port used for VirtualHosts (443). In your `Apache` folder, in conf/extra there should be a file called `http-vhosts.conf`

You should change all instances of 443 to a different port.

Change:

```
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
```

Then you should be good to run both services.

Comment: Port 443 is HTTPS and may or may not associated with virtual hosts.

Comment: 3 years later... This actually helped me, I replaced the `<VirtualHost *:80>` by `<VirtualHost localhost:8080>` in *http-vhosts.conf* having done what [ace suggested in *httpd.conf*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5456380/1326147) (i.e. no need for the `Listen` or the `NameVirtualHost` lines - @Anders I believe Skip had that 443 set by default, that's why he suggested to change all of them). I also placed 2 lines in [windows hosts like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23555524/1326147): `127.0.0.1 myproj.local`, `::1 myproj.local` and browse it through `http://myproj.local:8080`.

Answer (score 2):

In the WAMPSERVER 3.0.6 and above right Click WAMPSERVER icon and navigate to tools option.(only if its green color- i.e all services are running). It will list all the options for Apache and MySQL. Test the available port or if not click on 'Use a port other than 8080, it will give you a pop up box and you can enter the value and text the port.[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M97sW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Or like in my case, I wanted wamp to run on port :80 on a secondary ip on the same network card.
This allows me to use my main ip to run IIS on :80 and the secondary ip :80 apache.
How to get multiple IP's on same networkcard? [stackoverflow alias IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944860/how-to-create-an-ip-alias-on-windows)

1. Browse to 'C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf'
2. open httpd.conf
3. Look for Line ~72 Listen 0.0.0.0:80 and change this to the secondary ip (in my case 192.168.210.41:80).
4. I had to restart pc because IIS did not want to restart. Start IIS first, then Wamp.
   Works!

Answer (score -2):

You can run both server simultenously by changing port number of Apache or IIS.
**A)** How you can change Apache port number:

1) Open “httpd.conf” file located in folder “C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf”. You can also open file directly from system try if your wamp is running.
2) Search for “listen” text in file and update the default port 80 to 8080.
3) Now Restart the WAMP server to make new port number effective.
4) Open the browser with url “http://localhost:8080/” wamp will show home page.
Reff: http://sforsuresh.in/iis-and-wamp-servers-on-the-same-system/

**B)** How you can change IIS port:
1) Go start and type IIS.
2) IIS Manager will open. click on “Default Web Site” on left hand side.
3) click on “bindings…” from the right side action section.
4) Popup will open with 80 port listed. select it and click the edit button.
5) Update the port and restart the server.Now try to access using browser.

Reff: http://sforsuresh.in/change-iis-port-windows/

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers en masse. Instead, flag the questions as duplicates.