# WAMP - Remove localhost from project URL

Tags: php, apache, url, localhost, wamp

The URLs of my projects in WAMP are not resolving as I'd expect. For example, I'd expect the project in the folder c:\wamp\www\project1 to have the URL http://project1/, but it actually has the URL http://localhost/project1/.

This can cause problems when accessing server variables. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can also [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) specially if you are now using **WAMPServer 3** or greater, for a simple clikc and go way to create Virtual hosts.

Actually this change was intended by the WAMPServer developers and for a good reason.

There is a problem using the `localhost/project1` url and the default WAMPServer DocumentRoot in that it causes problems for some frameworks and WordPress type environments, as well as your own code if you are using code which depends on knowing anything about the server environment.

The correct solution is to create Virtual Hosts for all your projects even those that you store in the `\wamp\www\project1` style folders.

When doing that the DocumentRoot is `\wamp\www` and that is what causes these problems.

These tools expect the DocumentRoot to be the root of the site i.e. `\wamp\www\project1` so that when they use PHP variables like

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

they get the correct answer i.e. the answer they would get on a real live server hosting just that site.

So using the `localhost\project1` style url would mean these variables would return

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = localhost
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = localhost
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = C:/wamp/www
```

When they should return

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = project1
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = project1
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = C:/wamp/www/project1
```

So what you should do to make the `My Projects` menu work and reduce your pain in copying sites to live servers is:

Create an entry in the HOSTS file for each project like so and remember to create one for access via IPV4(127.0.0.1) and one for access via IPV6 (::1):-

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 project1

::1 localhost
::1 project1
```

Remember to refresh the Windows DNS Cache after any change to this file like so :-

Start a command window using `Run as Administrator` and run :-

```
net stop Dnscache
net start Dnscache
```

Now you must create a Virtual Host definition, so edit the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf` file ( apache versions may differ )

Delete the default stuff in there the first time you do this. And then create your Virtual Host definitions like so :-

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
# This next line is not required if you are using Apache 2.4.x and should be deleted
NameVirtualHost *:80

## should be first so the wamp menu page loads and is the default site
## should also never be changed from only allowing access from the local machine
## for a bit of extra security from casual ip address probing
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName  localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All

        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>

        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project1"
    ServerName  project1
    ServerAlias project1
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/project1">
        AllowOverride All

        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>

        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you need one more change, you must uncomment the line in `httpd.conf` that includes the above file we have just changed. So edit the `httpd.conf` file, use the wampmanager menus to do this as it ensures you edit the correct file.

Find this line `#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and remove the comment `#` symbol from the beginning of the line like so :-

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Now of course you will need to restart Apache so that it picks up your configuration changes.

If Apache does not restart, you probably made a mistake in the config, to find out what is wrong try this.

Open a command window and `CD` into the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin` folder.

Then run this :-

```
httpd -t
```

If the error is in `httpd.conf` or the `httpd-vhost.conf` files it will tell you the error and also give you the line number to make finding the error very easy.

Comment: At least now, I know why.
If the developers made this way I won't change it.

Thanks for the help and info.

Rafael de Castro - Brazil

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me on Apache 2.4.23, wamp shows two virtual hosts (localhost and project1), it links to "project1" however then it just opens the same wamp configuration page which is on the localhost... UPDATE: actually it works! I had to restart wamp services again. Many thanks!

Answer (score 14):

in your www folder open index.php
at line 30 change:
$suppress_localhost to be false

this is should look:

$suppress_localhost = **false**;

Comment: Update: there is a new way to do this shown here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40846681/3125936

Answer (score 12):

In your `www` folder open `index.php` at line 30. Here, change `$suppress_localhost` to be `false`. So, it is should look:

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

That was the quickest and easiest fix for me. I'm using 64 bit Wamp.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I had this problem. So, I troubleshooted the problem and traced it to an actual solution, NOT A HACK.

The **SOLUTION** :

1. Right-Click WAMP-server icon
2. Select `WAMP Settings`,
3. Select (enable) option `Add localhost in URL`

**DONE**. The remainder is FYI of how and why.

---

**Note**: localhost/myproject.php or myproject.php. Although the solution was already accepted, I saw some posts that got me confused. The accepted solution is based on a single project wrt different server applications, based on the OP's specific question, and how to influence that single project in question. But all the other solutions are hacks and don't really answer the solution to the OP's question, but do bring up a good point about the URL. So, according to the other "solutions", here is how to toggle the localhost reference in the URL. Hence my additional solution added to the mix.

---

```
This is a toggle switch.
```

---

Troubleshooting Process (no hacking involved):

---

Let's peek at the index.php

[image]

---

Let's look at the config file. Note the variables and Array?

[image]

---

Here is the array. A variable used earlier. Let's see... Oh, it tells us where and what to do.

[image]

---

As noted in the **SOLUTION**:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your wamp seems to be configured to run a website on the normally non-existant domain helloworld.

add:

```
 127.0.0.1    helloworld
```

inside this file: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Make sure you start your text editor with administrator privileges to be able to edit that file.

This will tell your computer that the otherwise non-existant domain `helloworld` should be resolved to your loop back address.

Comment: do you need to restart windows when you do this? (i was never sure)

Comment: @Dagon nope, normally you don't even need to restart your browser

Comment: If I do that the other projects will continue broken

Comment: @RafaeldeCastro please notice, in your hosts file you need `127.0.0.1    hello world` , even if there is a `127.0.0.1    localhost` in there.

Comment: @nl-x but if I have other project like MyNewSite... I'll have to edit the Host file again...and so on for any other project??

Comment: @RafaeldeCastro : yup. You will need to do that if you want to have each project on its own domain. Otherwise you can alway use `http://localhost/projectNameHere`

Comment: @nl-x Please, don't be offended but its not the right way to fix it. I never had this problem before and I'm sure that I cannot be obligated to take this steps for each project I start :/

Comment: @RafaeldeCastro Other than running your own DNS server and actually buy the domain names, all options now have been mentioned.

Comment: @nl-x
I just want the regular behavior of Wamp. If I click the project, it will run like in ANY other normal installation. What would happen if I have Xampp and the same problem appear?

It just CAN'T be the answer.

I'm trying google it for hours but I can't express the problem in a proper way...

Comment: @RafaeldeCastro : then what you should be looking for is a setting to tell wamp to use addresses in the form of `http://localhost/xxxxx` in stead of `http://xxxxx/`.

Comment: @nl-x
Got it! I'll start searching. Thanks man, and sorry if I offended you
:)

Comment: Actually Rafael @nl-x was on the right lines but there is actually a bit more to it than he thought. It takes 5 minutes to set up a Virtual host and edit the hosts file, less when you have a working example to copy/paste and the benefits will pay you that back 100 times.

Comment: Actually I am off course aware of the vhosts that need setting. But that part was already taken care off by wamp, as the project already appeared on the wamp page.

Answer (score 1):

For me was the easiest way go to http://localhost and in wampserver homepage use `Add a Virtual Host` (Tools section). There is nice and easy form to create alias without any problem (instead console when you using tray icon to create alias). No source edit, just using what wamp offers. Remember refresh DNS after creating of alias. Tested on Win10, WampServer 3.0.6 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtualhost like RiggsFolly said.

And try to uncomment `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If your "Your Projects" folder exists in "wamp/www/" and if you can see the localhost home page after starting wampserever correctly, and still you can't access your projects, then simply go to **"wamp/www/"** folder, open *index.php* and search for **$suppress_localhost** and set its value to **false**. Restart wampserver, go to localhost and try to access your project.

Answer (score 0):

HostnameLookups ON not OFF in httpd.conf with DocumentRoot changed or not.
tested in browser for 
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] 
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\wamp\www

In index.php 
line 338 

($suppress_localhost ? 'http://' : '')


change http://   to http://localhost/
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can create a **virtual host** using **`Add a virtual Host`** utility under **Tools** menu on localhost's homepage.
For more info on how to create a virtual host visit : [Step by step instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/39378798#39378798)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest and quickest way is to:

> Open index.php in your www folder >>> change: $suppress_localhost to
>   be false / no.

Comment: I'm glad to make the post more readable, can you tell me which part you don't understand please?

Comment: You have to insert the rout of the actions inside a quote or code block so to be readable from others. Any time! ;)

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer per se. It seems that the quickest way of removing a Virtual Host using WAMP is either not create one in the first place or be prepared to uninstall/reinstall it. What is the path to the config file to correct a errant and otherwise not malfunctioning WAMP Server?

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question? But if you are the WAMP control panel it has an option to open the various configs (for PHP, Apache, etc). In Windows the apache conf (httpd.conf) will be in the folder where you installed Apache (so probably  Program Files/WAMP?)

Answer (score -1):

i also faced same problem after installing new wamp setup on window 7, 64bit.
just change line no. 30
$suppress_localhost = false;
Its work for me.

Comment: This is working for me on windows 7 ultimate edition 64 bit although I installed wamp 32 bit edition

Answer (score -1):

Open index.php in www folder and set

$suppress_localhost = True;===>$suppress_localhost = false;

that is work.

Answer (score -1):

You can update "urlAddLocalhost" variable in "wamp64/wampmanager.conf" file to on/off. By default it is "off".
My wamp version is 3.0.6.

```
urlAddLocalhost = "off"
```

[image]