# PHP localhost issue. Folder not opening when clicked inside localhost

Tags: php, wampserver

I just installed WAMP server to start practicing PHP. I created a folder in www directory. However, when I try to run the file from localhost it does not run.

For ex, I created a folder `"test"` in www directory. I saved an HTML file called "test.html" inside the test folder. Basically I have saved it in `www --> test --> test.html`.

I started localhost in my browser. I found test folder there. But when I click that test folder, instead of opening as `"localhost/test"`, it is opening as just `"test/"`. How to make sure that the folder, when clicked inside localhost, should open as `"localhost/<foldername"` (in this case `"localhost/test"`).

When I type as `"localhost/test"` in my browser, it works fine. But when I go to localhost and click on `"test"` folder it does not open.

Please help me to overcome this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server

Comment: Read From Here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408143/wamp-missing-http-localhost-in-urls-wrong-wamp-projects-links

Answer (score 1):

You should type the file name and the extension to open the file from the local host as your file is not index.html
so you should go to "localhost/test/test.html" that would work 
if you want your file to

Comment: Thank you Mr. Samer Wagdy.. Thanks for clarifying it :)