# Hostname wrong in WampServer

Tags: php, wamp

I installed **Wamp** in my system. Not all is happened as good: When I type `localhost` in url. I get the WampServer default index page:

[image: WampServer default index page]

But then when I click on the *Test*-Project-Link the URL changes to "`http://test/`" and showing error message as

**This webpage is not available**

However when I type `http://localhost/test/` directly in URL the page is obtained as I wish.

Comment: do you have `.htaccess` file on your folders or root?

Comment: @Dev01 no, there is no .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open your www folder, open `index.php`, and line 30 :

Change :

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

To :

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

For more informations about this issue, please consult this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551763/wamp-remove-localhost-from-url).

Comment: My pleasure ;) Please mark the answer as accepted, so i can grab some juicy reputation !

Comment: sure buddy with pleasure!!

Comment: @johnkork: Thanks for picking up the duplicate. *Next* time please consider leaving a comment beneath the question pointing to the duplicate instead of duplicating material. This will help to improve the site (but sure, it will give you less reputation in the numbers sense). I hope it's understandable anyway.