# Can't get to local server in WAMP

Tags: wampserver

When I click localhost in the WAMP menu, the localhost homepage opens as normal. I then click on any of my projects and instead of activating the localhost URL it goes to the server (www) based URL. For instance, one of the projects is 'chrispowell100.co.uk' and I would expect the URL that opens to be localhost/chrispowell100.co.uk but it is actually chrispowell100.co.uk which activates the www version. This has only just started happening in the last few days - prior to that I have used WAMP without issue for several years. I thought at first this may be a W10 problem which is where I first noticed it but I have identical symptoms on W8. (If I type 'localhost/chrispowell100.co.uk' in the address bar, the correct, local version opens.) 
Can someone tell me what is happening and how to fix it?
Appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

On looking at the code for WAMP's index.php I came across $suppress_localhost variable. Googling that led me to [WAMP - Remove localhost from project URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551763/wamp-remove-localhost-from-url) which answers my question. Case closed.